# What does the comma mean between two matrices represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, dirac-delta, mathematica

For example [A,B] ?  It has been many years since I needed to know.

Comment: Usually it denotes the so-called "commutator": $[A,B] = AB - BA.$

Comment: And it is not just the comma - the square brackets are part of the notation for commutations. $(A,B)$ would not mean the commutator.

Comment: thank you.  I am trying to make this quantum mechanics Dirac notation make sense.

Answer (score 4):

It is common notation for the [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator). Specifically for matrices and linear operators, it is given by
$$[A,B] = AB - BA.$$